# selenium, jmeter (non gui) and chromedriver

Tags: selenium, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I created a script in Jmeter that works in the gui and I moved it to an AWS instance.
I'm using:
selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
ChromeDriver (v2.2)
Chromium 37.0.2062.120 Ubuntu 14.04
and Jmeter 2.11

The script works in the gui (where it reaches my site, logs in etc) but in the non gui mode I get this error in the log file:

```
2014/10/10 17:54:22 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Linux 3.13.0-36-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 21.32 seconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'ip-10-1-1-132', ip: '10.1.1.132', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-36-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
        at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:44)
        at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:16)
        at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:212)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:597)
        at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:961)
        at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:946)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:566)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:554)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the remote location also has the chromedriver.exe in the expected path?

Comment: So I got it working, kinda. It can test using 10 users but if I put in like 100 I get this: [8.474][SEVERE]: Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/root/.pki/nssdb): NSS error code: -8025

Comment: that is really a lot of chrome instances!! Is your aim is to  simulate load on the server? If yes, is there any reason for you not using simple HTTP sampler?

Comment: 1st question: how can you run an chromedriver.exe on Ubuntu?  2nd question: How do you launch a browser for your selenium test in non-gui mode?

Comment: My aim is to simulate 10000 users logging in and streaming a video for X minutes. And I'm using Chromedriver for linux.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of ChromeDriver from 2013, which in no way whatsoever is going to support v37 of Chrome.

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.11/notes.txt

```
----------ChromeDriver v2.11 (2014-10-07)----------
Supports Chrome v36-40
```

So I'd suggest upgrading to v2.11 and retrying & upgrade Selenium whilst you are at it, v2.35 of Selenium is also from 2013.

Comment: Yes, I upgraded to Selenium 2.39. I'll try upgrading chromedriver. Could that be the cause for the NSS errors?

Comment: Hmm, I upgraded both chromedriver and selenium but I still get Build info: version: '2.39.0'. How can I change that?

Comment: Update, upgrading the plugins helped. Now when I increase the users to 50 I intermittently get "<Unknown source>#22) in <Unknown source> at line number 22". Jmeter also randomly hangs. Any ideas?

Comment: As well as: Unable to receive message from renderer